Change matplotlib yaxis offset from 1e-5 to caps 1E-5
I have a plot in matplotlib and I can't get it to change from 1e-5 to 1E-5. I've tried a lot, this seems to be the closest:
ax.yaxis.get_offset_text().set_text(ax.yaxis.get_offset_text().get_text().replace('e', 'E'))
if I run print(ax.yaxis.get_offset_text().get_text().) it prints 1E-5, however the plot still shows 1e-5
I tried to run plt.draw() etc. but nothing seems to help. Any suggestions? (I only have the complete tick at the top, at the side it just says 1,2,3,4 etc., something that I like).
(I want to change this to 1E-5)


Maybe the simplest is to scale the data before plotting, and then either place a text there, or (better), include it into the axis label.

Seems like the lower case "e" is hardcoded here, unless you change to using mathtext or tex.

Based on @tmdavison finding I made a simple Mokeypatch to fix the issue:
def get_offset(self):
    """
    Return scientific notation, plus offset.
    """
    if len(self.locs) == 0:
        return ''
    if self.orderOfMagnitude or self.offset:
        offsetStr = ''
        sciNotStr = ''
        if self.offset:
            offsetStr = self.format_data(self.offset)
            if self.offset > 0:
                offsetStr = '+' + offsetStr
        if self.orderOfMagnitude:
            if self._usetex or self._useMathText:
                sciNotStr = self.format_data(10 ** self.orderOfMagnitude)
            else:
                sciNotStr = '1E%d' % self.orderOfMagnitude
        if self._useMathText or self._usetex:
            if sciNotStr != '':
                sciNotStr = r'\times\mathdefault{%s}' % sciNotStr
            s = fr'${sciNotStr}\mathdefault{{{offsetStr}}}$'
        else:
            s = ''.join((sciNotStr, offsetStr))
        return self.fix_minus(s)
    return ''
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter
ScalarFormatter.get_offset = get_offset
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

This solves the issue if it is different from E-5 (for example one of my axis was E-3)

This 'quick and dirty' solution sets the offset text to 1E-5 on both axes of my plot:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

x = np.linspace(1e-5, 3e-5, 10)

class PlainOffsetScalarFormatter(matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter):
    def get_offset(self):
        return '1E-5'

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(PlainOffsetScalarFormatter())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(PlainOffsetScalarFormatter())

plt.plot(x, x)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')

plt.savefig('test.png')

You can play around with get_offset if you want it to return something different. Also, if you want different offset texts on the x-axis and y-axis, you can implement two versions of the PlainOffsetScalarFormatter class.
